# How to filter the contents of a div via a dropdown box and hide the results until the option is picked. (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I gave this my best shot. Basically, I want to make a dropdown box that appears just like that - a dropdown box. Clean and simple. Then, when you click on a year, you get a list of text or links, whatever, of months for that year. Pretty basic right? I am failing terribly.

I think my issue is with my javascript/jquery.

Here is my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mvfehpp/5/)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$().ready(function() {
    $('.selectSome').on('change', function() {
        showHide();
    });
});

function showHide() {
    // hide all rows
    $('.row').hide();
   // show good row only

    }</script>
```

Comment: your fiddle is wrong, take out the html elements from the css and javascript (script and style tags)

Comment: You haven't failed. You hide all the rows.

Comment: also you have duplicate `id`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/1mvfehpp/9/

```
<label for="select_class">
  <select id="select_category" class="selectSome">
    <option value="null">Year</option>
    <option value="row_c1">2006</option>
    <option value="row_c2">2007</option>
    <option value="row_c3">2008</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Then added this jquery

```
$('#select_category').change(function () {
  $('.row').css("display","none");

  var fieldToShow = $(this).val();
  var className = fieldToShow.slice(-2);
  $("." + className).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".selectSome").on("change", function() {
        showHide();
    });
});

function showHide() {
    $('.row').hide();
    var selected = $("#select_category").val();
    $("." + selected).show(); //You have to select the elements which you need to show based on the value selected.
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1503/

Comment: The OP also has multiple ID's with the same name. I believe she needs to review the basics before manipulating the DOM.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah. True.

Comment: @Aaron in K K's example the ID's are irrelevant, sure it is not good to have same id's but in this example it does not matter.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I'm not talking about KK's example.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

- show current selected row
- hide all the remaining

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.selectSome').on('change', function(e) {
    $('div.' + this.value).show();
    $('div:not(.' + this.value + ')').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<label for="select_category">
    <select id="select_category" class="selectSome">
        <option value="null">Year</option>
        <option value="c1">2006</option>
        <option value="c2">2007</option>
        <option value="c3">2008</option>
    </select></label>
<hr />
<div class="row c1" id="row_c1">
    [one_third]BoD Meeting Minutes - December 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - November 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - October 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - September 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - August 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - July 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - June 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - May 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - April 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - March 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - February 2006<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - January 2006<br />[/one_third]
</div>
<div class="row c1" id="row_c1">
    [one_third]Directors' Meeting Minutes - December 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - November 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - October 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - September 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - August 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - July 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - June 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - May 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - April 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - March 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - February 2006<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - January 2006<br />[/one_third]
</div>
<div class="row c1" id="row_c1">
    [one_third_last]Membership Meeting Minutes - December 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - November 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - October 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - September 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - August 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - July 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - June 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - May 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - April 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - March 2006<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - January 2006<br />[/one_third_last]
</div>
<div class="row c2" id="row_c2">
    BoD Meeting Minutes - December 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - November 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - October 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - September 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - August 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - July 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - June 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - May 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - April 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - March 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - February 2007<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - January 2007<br /><br />
</div>
<div class="row c2" id="row_c2">
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - December 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - November 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - October 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - September 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - August 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - July 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - June 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - May 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - April 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - March 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - February 2007<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - January 2007<br /><br />
</div>
<div class="row c2" id="row_c2">
    Membership Meeting Minutes - December 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - November 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - October 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - September 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - August 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - July 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - June 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - May 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - April 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - March 2007<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - January 2007<br /><br />
</div>
<div class="row c3" id="row_c3">
    BoD Meeting Minutes - December 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - November 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - October 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - September 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - August 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - July 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - June 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - May 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - April 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - March 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - February 2008<br />
    BoD Meeting Minutes - January 2008<br /><br />
</div>
<div class="row c3" id="row_c3">
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - December 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - November 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - October 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - September 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - August 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - July 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - June 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - May 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - April 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - March 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - February 2008<br />
    Directors' Meeting Minutes - January 2008<br /><br />
</div>
<div class="row c3" id="row_c3">
    Membership Meeting Minutes - December 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - November 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - October 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - September 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - August 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - July 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - June 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - May 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - April 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - March 2008<br />
    Membership Meeting Minutes - January 2008<br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure where my comment went, but I mentioned that I like this approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than 1 unique id per page but this jquery will work if you fix that

```
$().ready(function() {
$('.selectSome').on('change', function() {
    showHide($(this).val());
});
});

function showHide(val) {
// hide all rows
$('.row').hide();
// show good row only
$("#row_"+val).show();
}
```

Comment: This one will not work as it sits, OP has multiple div's with the same ID, change the id portion to classes and I will give you a plus one.